# Chat online using asp.net or mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sockets, webforms

Is it possible to develop a chat online using Sockets in asp.net web form or mvc platform?
please give me a sample code if it is possible and say why if not possible

Answer (score 0):

Use [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), it handles all the plumbing you will need.

Comment: very thanks about your answer mr Ian Mercer ,but my problem is that i do not want to use webSocket (that need html5) and i can not use net 4.5 , cause my win server is not 8 and dose not support net 4.5. by the way i want to use system.net , system.net.sockets namespaces for this application

Comment: SignalR does not require WebSockets, it falls back to long polling or server side events.  You should explain in your question why you *cannot* use the normal protocols used for web chat applications otherwise it's likely to be closed as 'too localized'.

Comment: sorry . but i want use only system.net , system.net.sockets namespaces in .net 4 or earlier versions . cause this is not my project and i am forced to use this namespaces.is it possible ? thank you very much.